# iPad web app, embedding google maps

Tags: ios, html, iphone-web-app

I making prototype web app for iPad, and I want to embed google map.

I embedded map with this if frame code from google's tutorial:

```
<iframe width="720" height="340" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" src="http://maps.google.com/maps?f=q&amp;source=s_q&amp;hl=en&amp;geocode=&amp;q=Belgrade,+Serbia&amp;aq=0&amp;sll=37.0625,-95.677068&amp;sspn=38.638819,79.013672&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;hq=&amp;hnear=Belgrade,+City+of+Belgrade,+Central+Serbia,+Serbia&amp;ll=44.809,20.465641&amp;spn=0.022226,0.062571&amp;z=14&amp;output=embed"></iframe>
```

But, in safari I get map with some withe rectangle: http://cl.ly/2u2G0p1T3x3O1Q1X3A1B
and when I add this web app to my homescreen, I don't get map, I get white div: http://cl.ly/0O3n2c3N3C0C1F2x0l2a

Where is some other way to implement google map on iPad web app? :|

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't tried making an app yet but I would probably try using [Googles javascript api](http://code.google.com/intl/en/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/) instead of an iframe. I believe your amount of control is much better with js than with the static version.